# Stil ist es erst dann, wenn man selbst keinen mehr hat

Tags: phrase-request, reference-request

Lang ist’s her, aber ich schwöre Stein und Bein: Irgendjemand in der Kunstgeschichte sagte zu mir:

> Stil ist es erst dann, wenn man selbst keinen mehr hat.

In der Bedeutung: Einen epochenbegreifenden Stil *sinnvoll benennen* zu können, ist erst in der Retrospektive, also nach Abschluss der Epoche, überhaupt möglich.

Nun erinnere ich mich nicht mehr daran, wer genau das war. Die dominante Suchmaschine völlig unbenutzbar geworden für so etwas.  Aber als Bonmot ist das doch zu schön, ohne einen konkreten Nachweis dafür auf SE parat zu haben.

Kann das, in leicht abgewandelter Form, von Loos sein? Wie lautet die exakte Phrase, das genaue Zitat?

Comment: Wird der Name *Google* vom System nicht mehr akzeptiert, oder wieso steganografierst Du das so?

Answer (score 4):

Der Literaturprof Jost Hermand hat mal gesagt:

> Von Epochenstilen redet man erst dann, wenn man selber keinen mehr hat, oder sich wenigstens unsicher in dieser Hinsicht fühlt.

Das könnte möglicherweise dein Zitat sein. Das ist allerdings kein Zitat zur Kunstgeschichte, sondern zur Literatur.

Comment: Das dort ausgedrückte Gefühl *und* die Rationalität trifft's  schon mal recht gut.  Auch der Bezug zu Epochen stimmt. However, '66 ist wohl zu spät.